# Remapping right command and option on a MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, remapping, key-binding

First of all, I am pretty new to MacOs, I've been Windows and Linux user for a long time.

I have been tinkering a lot with the remaping/shortcuts in macOS Big Sur so I can be comfortable while programming. I am using tools such as Karabiner and BetterTouchTool to manage the key binds.

I am reaching that level of comfortability with all the changes, but one is being pretty resistant: Right command and option. What I would like is:

- Right cmd -> cmd + left arrow key (go to beginning of the current line).
- Right option -> cmd + right arrow key (go to end of the current line).

I have seen things like [this](https://gist.github.com/trusktr/1e5e516df4e8032cbc3d), but I can't seem find a way to specify "right" command/options through the DefaulKeyBindings.dict

Does anyone have any suggestion about how I could do this?

Thank you!

Comment: [Key Codes](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) (freeware) will help you identify the difference in codes sent - idk how you'd map that into keybindings etc

Comment: Thank you! I will try that.